# change the objects inside functions

Tags: c++, class, function

I have a function which has two parameters, both objects. I change these objects inside the function and I need to see the changes afterwards. But pointers does not work. Any idea?

```
void foo(apple &a,apple &b)
{
  //change a and b
}
main()
{
  apple a,b;
  foo(a,b);
  //a and b are the same as befor calling foo  `  
}
```

thanks.

Comment: How are you "changing" this objects inside the method?

Comment: Please post some *actual* compilable code that demonstrates the problem.  The principle of passing references to objects ought to be correct.

Comment: And pointers should also work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean changing the methods of the classes you're passing? You'll need to use '->' if that's what you mean.

```
class apple {
    public:
        int weight; 
}

void foo(apple *a,apple *b) {
    a->weight = b->weight;
}

main() {
    apple a,b;
    foo(&a,&b);
}
```